# How to show multiple records fetched from a table in parse.com

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I am using Parse for my app. I have two tables StudentDetail and Subject,as user enters his name, the id is queried from studentDetail table. and using that id i want to fetch rest of the details of Subject table.Data fetched through this code is correct but in $scope.subs i.e 19th line it overrides the data and returns only the last record,i want to store all the records in $scope.subs object iteratively.

```
$scope.subjectFetch= function(form,form1) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(StudentDetail);
    var querySub = new Parse.Query(Subject);
    query.equalTo("Firstname",form1.Firstname);
        query.find({
       success: function(results) {
             stdId = results[0].id;
             querySub.equalTo("StudentId",stdId);
            querySub.find({
                    success: function(subjects) {
                        alert("Success");
                  for (var i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++) { 
                   var object = subjects[i];
                      subname = object.get('Name');
                      credits = object.get('credits');
                      code =object.get('code');
                      duration = object.get('duration');
                      alert("Subject name: "+subname+"\n Credits :"+credits+"\n Code :"+code+"\n Duration:"+duration);
                     $scope.subs=[{Name:subname,credits:credits,code:code,duration:duration},{Name:"xyz",credits:5}];
                     //console.log($scope.subs);
                }
              },
              error: function(error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
              }
            });
       },
           error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `$scope.subs` to be a new array with a single object in it inside your loop, which is why only the last one is there when it is done.

Try the following success handler instead:

```
success: function(subjects) {
    // reset subs array
    $scope.subs = [];
    for (var i in subjects) {
        var subject = subjects[i];
        // push new object into the array
        $scope.subs.push({
            Name: subject.get('Name'),
            credits: subject.get('credits'),
            code: subject.get('code'),
            duration: subject.get('duration')
        });
    }
    // log the populated array
    console.log($scope.subs);
```

Alternatively if you use something like the Underscore library, you can just map the items:

```
// replace success function body with this:
$scope.subs = _.map(subjects, function(subject) {
    return {
        Name: subject.get('Name'),
        credits: subject.get('credits'),
        code: subject.get('code'),
        duration: subject.get('duration')
    };
});
console.log($scope.subs);
```